# Edits no longer have a grace period?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

Usually [edits made within 5 minutes of making or editing a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info) are rolled into a single revision in the edit history. However, it looks like edits are getting listed separately even if they were within the grace period.

[image: Question history showing two tag edits within 5 minutes]

Comment: Not just tag edits. [The grace period is gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387167/158792), period.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a regression. We're working on restoring the proper grace period edit functionality and will update here once complete.

**Update:** Grace period edits have been restored. I was hoping it would have been released quick enough for me to have a grace period edit, but alas my punishment is another revision on this answer. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: It seems like [this prior bug of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381460/unable-to-submit-grace-period-edits-to-tag-wikis-using-the-edit-tag-info-butto) was fixed - were the changes here meant to resolve it? [This other grace period bug of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385652/when-submitting-a-tag-wiki-edit-from-the-revision-history-during-the-grace-perio) still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Looks like that bug report was never triaged. While I'm still working in that area I'll take a peek at repro-ing on my end.

Comment: " punishment is another revision on this answer" - Proper Karmic Punishment :D

Comment: Nuking grace period is impressive achievement, so I'm impressed. :-D

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I repro'd locally. Will update on your linked post when the fix is deployed.

Comment: @TylerMcEntee huh? Thought the bug was fixed two days ago. Was there another regression? Can't see any report or new comment from Sonic.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I'm referring to the bug listed here in Sonic's answer comment: [tag wiki grace period edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385652/when-submitting-a-tag-wiki-edit-from-the-revision-history-during-the-grace-perio)