# Grace period removed?

Tags: bug, grace-period

The grace period has disappeared.

For example, the history of [this now-deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75631261/589924) shows an edit five and ten seconds after posting.

[image: Edits 5s and 10s after post]

Is that intentional? I don't see an announcement.

Comment: Reproduced here in the question and I think I see it on every post on the linked question. Only very low rep users (<10) are supposed to create revisions every time they edit. No comments were posted and I didn't edit any tags (but it's probably the same issue as the other post).

Comment: I mention it because it's not the first time the grace period has been removed accidentally.